# Swift: batch assign struct member from array of values

Tags: swift

I am reading settings from a block of swift Data, and would like to populate it into a struct for easy access and type correctness. Is there a succinct way to assign the value to the struct members? e.g using subscripts to self?

```
let settings : [UInt] = [5, 5, 121, 700, 108, 1452, 6655, 10]

struct Header {
    var version             : UInt8?
    var options             : UInt8?
    var records             : UInt16?
    var timeout             : UInt16?
    var left                : UInt16?
    var right               : UInt16?
    var middle              : UInt16?
    var speed               : UInt8?

    init(values: [UInt]) {
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        var labels : [String] = []
        for (n, _) in m.children {
            labels.append(n!)
        }

        for (h, v) in zip(labels, values) {
            print("\(h) -> \(v)")
            self[h] = v     //error: type 'Header' has no subscript members
        }
    }
}

let h = Header(values: settings)
```

**Follow up**
Thanks for the solution, ColGraff.

In my case data comes in from multiple places, in the form of an array of value. The following will help

```
let settings : [UInt] = [5, 5, 121]
let labels : [Header.Keys] = [.version, .options, .records]
var data : [Header.Keys : UInt] = [:]
zip(labels, settings).forEach { data[$0] = $1 }
```

Comment: Seeing that self isn't a Dictionary or Array, subscript isn't going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A widely-accepted way of doing something like you say is:

```
struct Header {
  let version : UInt
  let options : UInt
  let records : UInt
}

// adds marshaling from a `Dictionary`
extension Header {
  enum Keys: String { case version, options, records}

  init?(settings: [Keys:UInt]) {
    guard let version = settings[.version] else { return nil }
    guard let options = settings[.options] else { return nil }
    guard let records = settings[.records] else { return nil }
    self = Header(version: version, options: options, records: records)
  }
}

let data: [Header.Keys: UInt] = [.version: 5, .options: 5, .records: 121]

if let foo = Header(settings: data) {
  print(foo) // Header(version: 5, options: 5, records: 121)
}
```

If you like you can replace a structure like a `Dictionary` with an `Array` or even a `String` but a `Dictionary` is very natural structure for what you are asking. Some people even do this with things like `JSON` strings encoding `Dictionary` or `Array` structures.

Yes, you could possibly use a `Mirror` to do something like this in a more automatic manner but it can be tricky and cause problems down the line. Writing a more concrete way of marshaling your data is often safer.

A more advanced usage and discussion is in [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152352/swift-marshaling).

Comment: This is good. Can you add an example of how you would create an instance of the struct?

Comment: I'm grabbing this as a gist. It seems like a very useful pattern.

Comment: It does add a bit of boilerplate but overall it's very useful. There are libraries out there that automate this sort of thing but I prefer to do it by hand for clarity. For completeness you might want to add a version key and version your object's marshaling, that will future-proof it if you are loading the structure from a file or other source. Then you can write a marshaling method for each version and do stuff like backwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate Inspired Solution:**

```
let settings : [UInt] = [5, 5, 121, 700, 108, 1452, 6655, 10]

enum Fields: String {
    case version, options, records, timeout, left, right, middle, speed
}

struct Header {
    var version             : UInt8?
    var options             : UInt8?
    var records             : UInt16?
    var timeout             : UInt16?
    var left                : UInt16?
    var right               : UInt16?
    var middle              : UInt16?
    var speed               : UInt8?

    init(values: [UInt]) {
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        var labels : [Fields] = []
        for (n, _) in m.children {
            labels.append(Fields(rawValue: n!)!)
        }

        zip(labels, values).forEach { l, v in
            switch l {
            case .version:  self.version = UInt8(v)
            case .options:  self.options = UInt8(v)
            case .records:  self.records = UInt16(v)
            case .timeout:  self.timeout = UInt16(v)
            case .left   :  self.left    = UInt16(v)
            case .right  :  self.right   = UInt16(v)
            case .middle :  self.middle  = UInt16(v)
            case .speed  :  self.speed   = UInt8(v)
            default: ()
            }
        }
    }
}

var h = Header(values: settings)
print(h.version)
h.version = 7
print(h.version)
```

Now if I could only figure out how to *generate* the enum dynamically from the struct...